# Firebase Database for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app with Firebase for iOS and Android. Now I have a problem. For me it's not possible to read Firebase Database data in my Android app. I've watched many Tutorials, but it won't work. Even the Firebase Documentation couldn't help me.
I want to read data from the database and put them into a label.
Can somebody help me?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to put the code in this Question.

Here is the whole Code of my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView readText;
Button readButton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    readText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readView);
    readButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readBtn);




    readButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            DatabaseReference mChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://myapplication-6ddba.firebaseio.com/").child("hallowelt").child("lol");

            mChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  // String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                    readText.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });

}
```

}

I am using the latest version of Firebase.

These are the Firebase Database Rules:

```
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": false }
```

Comment: yeah sure! please show the code that you are using to read data

Comment: there are two different and easy ways to read data from firebase! I can guide but please first show me what firebase version have you integrated for firebase and what are your proguard rules for the project!

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference.child("hallowelt").child("lol"); try this.!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to access the Database via `DatabaseReference mChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://myapplication-6ddba.firebaseio.com/").child("hallowelt").child("lol");`?

From my understanding, something like `DatabaseReference mChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("hallowelt").child("lol");` should be enough, if you linked your project to the Database correctly.